# no visualiza valor correcto de campo booleano en flask-wtform

Tags: html, booleano, flask-wtf

Hice un simple `abm` con **flask wtform** y **sqalchemy (sqlite3)**. Los datos en la base me los almacena bien, pero al momento de visualizar un registro existente, en la vista me muestra todo, salvo los campos booleanos, que me los muestra como false y en realidad en la base tiene un valor true. Si me pueden ayudar desde ya lo agradezco porque esto no me deja avanzar.
En el `form` lo defini así

```
class FormOt(FlaskForm):
 ...
    internet_adsl = BooleanField('Internet Adsl', default=False)
 ...
```

En la base de datos el campo esta definido así

```
 ...
    internet_adsl = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
 ...
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

por suerte pude solucionarlo. Comparto solución por si a alguno le sirve, ya que hace tiempo que vengo lidiando con esto.

En la vista, cuando valido si el campo del form es booleano, pregunto si el valor del campo es 1 o 0, dependiendo de esto en la mascara paso checked=True o checked=False

Copio macro resumida, en donde se compara la parte booleana

```
{% if field.type == 'BooleanField' %}
    {% if field() == 1 %}
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            {{ field(checked=True, class='form-check-input') }}
            {{ field.label.text|safe }}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            {{ field(checked=False, class='form-check-input') }}
            {{ field.label.text|safe }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Saludos